# How to create view with two counts having different where clause from same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables

**Schools**

```
CREATE TABLE Schools 
(
        BlockID INT,
        SchoolID VARCHAR, 
        SchoolName VARCHAR, 
        powerAvail BIT, 
        waterAvail BIT 
)
```

**Blocks**

```
CREATE TABLE Blocks 
(
    BlockID INT,
    BlockName VARCHAR 
)
```

Inserting values:

```
Insert into Schools (1, 1, 'a', 0, 1)
Insert into Schools (2, 2, 'b', 1, 1)
Insert into Schools (2, 3, 'c', 0, 1)

Insert into Blocks (1, 'A')
Insert into Blocks (2, 'B')
```

Now I have to create a view to list 3 columns: Block Name, Number of schools in a block with power available 1, Number of schools in a block with water available 1 
grouping result by block name.

**Note**: the power available condition should not be dependent on water available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
SELECT B.BlockName,
    SUM(CAST(powerAvail as int)) as num_powerAvail,
    SUM(CAST(waterAvail as int)) as num_waterAvail
FROM Schools S JOIN
     Blocks  B
     ON S.BlockID = B.BlockID
GROUP BY B.BlockName;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can join tables School and Blocks on BlockID then do a sum when power or water available is 1.

```
SELECT 
    B.BlockName,
    SUM(case when powerAvail=1 then 1 else 0 end) as 'Count_Schools_Power_Available',
    SUM(case when waterAvail=1 then 1 else 0 end) as 'Count_Schools_Water_Available'
FROM
    Schools S,
    Blocks  B
WHERE
    S.BlockID = B.BlockID
GROUP BY
    B.BlockName;
```

Result:

```
BlockName   Count_Schools_Power_Available   Count_Schools_Water_Available
   A        0                               1
   B        1                               2
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged